# Protractor: deleteAllCookies not working

Tags: angularjs, cookies, protractor

I need to delete the browser cookies after each test in protractor. I am calling the following method to clear all cookies.

```
 this.After(function () {
    browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
  })
```

Although this method is called after each test it does not clear the cookies.

Answer (score -1):

get the logout URL and then delete cookies.

```
this.After(function () {
    browser.get('#/Logout');
    browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
  })
```